# Is Breast Milk ritually impure?

Tags: halal-haram, taharah, najis

Recently when I was praying some milk started coming out of my breasts. Basically I was breastfeeding my son so after that I started to pray without a bra. After the prayer my husband saw some milk on my clothes and told me.

My question is does breast milk make clothes Impure to pray in? My husband didn't know the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Would Allah allow you to feed your baby something impure?

Milk is not among the things that break wudu': [Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu)

In verse ([16:66](http://legacy.quran.com/16/66)) milk was declared as pure:

> ... We give you drink from what is in their bellies - between excretion and blood - pure milk, palatable to drinkers.

The scholars are in full consent that it is pure, here a statement of the hanbali scholar 'ala' ad-Dyn al-Mardaawi  [علاء الدين المرداوي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A):

> Al-Mardaawi (may Allah have mercy on him):
>
> Milk of humans and animals that may be eaten is taahir, and there is no scholarly conflict on this point.
>
> End quote from al-Insaaf, 1/343 (source islamqa [#167149](https://islamqa.info/en/167149))

You may find similar statements from scholars of other madhabs in this fatwa on [islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/185819) (in Arabic)

Imam al-Qurtobi his [tafsir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=16&ayano=66) even quotes a dispute about the purness of breast milk of a dead woman. While al-Jassass in [his tafssir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=212&surano=16&ayano=66) even discusses the purness of the breast milk of dead cattle saying that the fact that the verse above is a general declaration of pureness.