# While taking wudu my bicep touched something in the bathroom does that mean my wudu is nullified

Tags: wudu

While I was taking wudu my bicep bymistakely touch a piece of wood in the bathroom does that nullify my wudu. Because it just eats me when I pray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu)

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not. The following are the things that nullify wudu:
1 – Any najasah, liquid or solid matter coming out of the penis and anus like urine, feces, sperm, madi, blood, etc.
2 – Breaking wind from the anus (farting).
3 – Blood, pus, yellow liquid, etc flowing from any part of the body.
Remember Islam is suppose to be easy, don't stress over punitive matters. :) -Michelle