# Does vaping invalidate salah?

Tags: salat, wudu, smoking

Salam alaykum rahmutallah wabaraktuhu brothers and sisters! I have a very important question. Does smoking vapes invalidate salah or nullify your wudu? I know it's haram and I am quitting but I've heard that it invalidates your salah for 40 days and I'm afraid my salah won't be accepted during Ramadan.

Comment: Relevant: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/27143/will-the-prayers-of-one-who-drinks-alcohol-not-be-accepted-for-forty-days

Answer (score 1):

Vaping does **not** nullify wudu. See [Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/) for a comprehensive list of things which invalidate wudu.

Vaping does **not** invalidate salah. The hadith about prayer not being accpted for forty days is regarding wine. And even for that case it does not mean that the salah is invalid.

> The fact that his prayers are not accepted **does not mean that they are not valid**, or that he should give up praying, rather it means that he will not be rewarded for them.
>
> So the benefit of praying will be that he will have discharged his duty and will not be punished for not doing it.
>
> <sup>— [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/27143/)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

**There are Two Question ...**

***Does vaping break wudu?***

**There Different opinion about Wudu**

Some Scholar say break wudu and some say not

**but Smoking will make your mouth malodor**, When prophet (SW) said ,  'Whoever eats (from) this plant (he meant garlic) should keep away from our mosque."

Without cleaning your mouth you can not enter the mosques .. (***Personal Opinion***) better do wudu again...

***Does vaping invalidate salah?***

No rule of 40 days or any other rule applies,

***There is no evidence/source that, invalidates your salat for 40 days***

But Allah said about in The holy Quran that "avoid it that you may be successful.",
when  the salat is the key of jannah ...

**Reference**

> [160-Chapter:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10)
> I heard Jabir bin `Abdullah saying, "The Prophet (ﷺ) said, 'Whoever eats (from) this plant (he meant garlic) should keep away from our mosque." I said, "What does he mean by that?" He replied, "I think he means only raw garlic."

> In Surah Al-Maidah, Allah says:
> O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah], and divining arrows are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful.
> [5 - Al-Ma'ida : 90](https://qurano.com/en/5-al-ma-ida/verse-90/)

> Satan only wants to cause between you animosity and hatred through intoxicants and gambling and to avert you from the remembrance of Allah and from prayer. So will you not desist?[5 - Al-Ma'ida : 91](https://qurano.com/en/5-al-ma-ida/verse-91/)

> And spend in the way of Allah and do not throw [yourselves] with your [own] hands into destruction [by refraining]. And do good; indeed, Allah loves the doers of good
> [2- Al-Baqara : 195](https://qurano.com/en/4-an-nisa/verse-19/)