# Is prayer invalid/prohibited after 40 days of pubic hair?

Tags: salat

I am confused if prayer is makru or invalid if the pubic area is more than 40 days?

Comment: there is no confusion here. the length of the pubic hair is not something that invalidates prayer. do you have any proof/evidence to support your confusion?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu). The question was asked by you!

Comment: actually he is not asking things that invalidate wudu. I have also heard this from one of my friend similar to what he asked, of course these things may not have any basis in Islam. So if someone knowledgeable confirm it is just false, then this question can be kept open so someone who has similar doubt can find it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting pubic hair is prescribed in Islam. And 40 days is reported as the upper limit of time before which they should be removed.

> قال أنس - وقت لنا في قص الشارب، وتقليم الأظفار، ونتف الإبط، وحلق العانة، أن لا نترك أكثر من أربعين ليلة
>
> Anas said: 'A time limit was set for us for trimming the moustache, clipping the nails, plucking the armpit hairs and shaving the pubes: that was not to be left for more than forty days.'
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:258)</sup>

The below linked fatawa have expressed that they could not find any evidence which associates validity of prayer with pubic hair. Prayer is valid as long as its conditions are met such as purity of the body, clothes, place, having done wudu or ghusl as needed, covering of the 'awrah.

The only conceivable way pubic hair could invalidate prayer is if they interfere with purity: for example if the hair are not kept clean or if they carry some filth like urine, ejaculate, blood etc.

**Ref:**

- https://islamqa.info/en/answers/1177/ (English)

  > However, leaving them for more than forty days does not have any effect on the validity of a person’s prayer,
- https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/107473/ and https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/120456/

  > وأما الحديث المذكور في السؤال فلم نقف عليه ... ولم نقف على قول لأهل العلم ببطلان صلاة من ترك حلق عانته
- [https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/12857/](https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/12857/%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B7-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A9)