# What happens if you wearing socks but went outside and there a lot of rain and dirty puddle caused by the rain touch you socks does it break wudu?

Tags: wudu

So basically i was walking home and it was raining a lot and my shoes touch the dirty puddle and I i didn't know it was an dirty puddle and it splashed over my socks but it quickly dried so does it break wudu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu)

Answer (score 1):

According to [terms of breaking the Wudu](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu) if your foot or shoes or socks touch the dirt puddle the Wudu does not break.

Only if you are sure the puddle contains anything Najis, then washing the touched part is needed to that part become pure.

Comment: Allah swt is the most merciful and most forgiving may Allah swt guide to Islam and forgive all you sins make you go jannat al firadus highest rank of heaven and you family and friends as well may Allah swt guide them both and you aswell Ameen❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤